# Laravel Scheduler - specify sender when using emailOutputTo()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scheduler, laravel-mail

How to specify sender for email reports which are sent by using [`emailOutputTo()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#task-output) of Laravel Scheduler?

Currently `from` header is empty and I see in Gmail:

[image]

[image]

---

My code is:

```
$schedule->command('some:task')
    ->dailyAt('05:30')
    ->sendOutputTo(config('path.logs') . '/output.log')
    ->emailOutputTo('email@example.com');
```

---

I'm using built-in [Laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail) provider with `mailgun` driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the desired "from" in /config/mail.php:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'john.smith@gmail.com', 'name' => 'John Smith'],
```

Comment: Thanks @MrCode! This is exactly what I missed :)